# How to find sum of two cells with same row names in a dataframe (Pandas)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

In advance i am sorry if this already been answered before but im having a hard time figuring this out.
[DataFrame]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/k4C8O.png

Problem: First I want to compare two string values[InputType] from the dataframe and if they matches, I want to add the corresponding numbers in another cell[actual values]

As an example: I want to calculate the total cost of alcohol from the above table.
TLS Downstairs Bar Alcohol + TLS Restaurant Alcohol
1397.82 + 255.36 = 1653.179
Since they both have the word 'alcohol' in them and I want to calculate the sum of ActualValues

df['ActualValue'][0] + df['ActualValue'][5]
This gives me the total cost but idk how to match string 'alcohol' only if they match finding the total.

Btw im new to python and pandas and numpy. Can someone help to figure this out. Forever grateful for any help and sorry for my broken grammar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming a dataframe called `df`, you can use `loc` to filter for rows that contain the word `Alcohol` (with `.str.contains('Alcohol')`) and take the `.sum()` of all those values:

```
df.loc[df['InputType'].str.contains('Alcohol'), 'ActualValue'].sum()
```

OR case insensitively:

```
df.loc[df['InputType'].str.contains('Alcohol', case=False), 'ActualValue'].sum()
```

Comment: Now it filters the two values which is great. Is there anyway to sum and get the number 1653.179?

Comment: does `df.loc[df['InputType'].str.contains('Alcohol', case=False), 'ActualValue'].sum()` work?

Comment: Yes sir. You made my day man. Thank you very much :)